# uses undefined struct compile error - C

Tags: c, windows, mongoose-web-server

The compiler doesn't know where stat.h is?

Error:
c:\Projects\ADC_HCI\mongoose.c(745) : error C2079: 'st' uses undefined struct '_stat64'

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static int
mg_stat(const char *path, struct mgstat *stp)
{
    struct  _stat64 st; //<-- ERROR

    int     ok;
    wchar_t     wbuf[FILENAME_MAX];

    to_unicode(path, wbuf, ARRAY_SIZE(wbuf));
    if (_wstat64(wbuf, &st) == 0) {
        ok = 0;
        stp->size = st.st_size;
        stp->mtime = st.st_mtime;
        stp->is_directory = S_ISDIR(st.st_mode);
    } else {
        ok = -1;
    }

    return (ok);
}
```

...downloaded the files straight from the [source](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/w/list).

Comment: Ask about it at the mongoose support group at http://groups.google.com/group/mongoose-users/topics - the maintainer is extremely helpful.

Comment: yeah, I just asked the group too....

Comment: I just looked at your post there - what kind of VS project are you using? IIRC, you need to build it as a multi-threaded console application.

Comment: I am compiling as /MT now as I will need that however, still have error.

Comment: Someone pointed out _stat64 in stat.h is double underscore....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff(VS.80).aspx): `_wstat64` takes a parameter of `struct __stat64` (with *two* underscores).  Redeclare your variable `st` to be of type `struct __stat64`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that neither `_stat64` nor `__stat64` is 'standard' in the sense of documented by any standard, such as POSIX.  You would normally use `struct stat`; if you are worried about whether that will work with big files (over 2 GiB), then check what compilation options are required on your platform to obtain 'large file support'.  For 64-bit machines and 64-bit compilations (not necessarily Windows 64), you usually don't need to worry.  You can often obtain large file support using:

```
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
```

These are at least semi-standardized.  Systems such as `autoconf` detect these things automatically (if you ask them to do so).

Answer (score 1):

Change the _stat64 to stat64. At least in my Linux machines that's the name of the structure. I don't know if it is different in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to sync to SVN trunk.

If you don't have SVN client, simply download two files:
http://mongoose.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mongoose.h (and .c file too)

The reason is that recently the code was refactored, and CRT _stat function was substituted 
with WinAPI one, GetFileAttributesExW().